# imagemagick make pdf of a fixed size out of multiple images

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I found some answers to this question but somehow nothing works for me (even though logically it should, at least with my knowledge)

I have three images `file1.png`, `file2.png` and `file3.png` with these properties:

```
identify file*.png
file1.png PNG 4961x7016 4961x7016+0+0 8-bit sRGB 12.6135MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
file2.png PNG 4961x7016 4961x7016+0+0 8-bit sRGB 22.8132MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
file3.png PNG 4961x7016 4961x7016+0+0 8-bit sRGB 14.887MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

now I used this imagemagick command `convert file*.png -page A4 file.pdf` to make a pdf with one image at each page. The problem with that one is, that the resulting pdf is with 52 MB way too big (since the input pictures are huge too). In addition, my pdfviewer displays me that the resulting pdf has a papersize of `25×36 mm`(A10) instead of the desired `210×297 mm`(A4).

I already tried to work with resize, but somehow I don't quite understand how set the sizes to get a A4 output (this is my main goal for now).

Does someone know why `page A4` didn't work or how to actually get an output pdf with the papersize of `A4`?

PS:

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-25 Q16 x86_64 2020-08-01 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fontconfig freetype heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png raqm raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

EDIT1 (identify output):

```
identify -verbose file.pdf
Image:
  Filename: file.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 71x101+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 0.986111x1.40278
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianness: Undefined
  Depth: 16/8-bit
[...]
```

```
identify file.pdf
file.pdf[0] PDF 71x101 71x101+0+0 16-bit sRGB 7412B 0.000u 0:00.000
file.pdf[1] PDF 71x101 71x101+0+0 16-bit sRGB 11518B 0.000u 0:00.000
file.pdf[2] PDF 71x101 71x101+0+0 16-bit sRGB 8394B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

EDIT2: See two test pngs here [(https://mega.nz/folder/O4Fm1aoK#ppeQD4ZycDMKhC2DctJ-UA)](https://mega.nz/folder/O4Fm1aoK#ppeQD4ZycDMKhC2DctJ-UA) (sadly I cannot upload the pdf to stackOverflow)

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
Still doesn't work when converting to pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me if I add the units and density in ImageMagick.

```
convert Untitled* -units pixelsperinch -density 72 -resize 595x842 result.pdf
```

```
identify -verbose result.pdf
```

```
Image:
  Filename: result.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 595x841+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 8.26389x11.6806
...
```

You may have found a deficiency in ImageMagick. The units and density need to be provided, I believe, since PNG stores that information in pixelspercentimeter, but PDF needs it in pixelsperinch.

Comment: Oh yes the units were the problem. In your example below, you didn't specify the units, but nevertheless it worked. Is there a trick, to set some kind of default for this? (or do you know why it worked without `-units`?)

Comment: It worked because the images created were not in pixelspercentimeter units. I think the default for xc: is pixelsperinch

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thanks for your help (and your time) and thanks for the explanation ;)

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, -page is a setting not an operator and so does not resize. You need to use -resize of each image to the pixel dimensions of A4 (595 x 842).

```
convert file1.png file2.png file3.png -resize 595x842 result.pdf
```

Comment: Hm, after applying this command, the pdf viewer still shows that the resulting pdf has the format `A10`. And being curious, from where did you get the pixel dimensions of A4 and don't they be variable, based on the resolution? Maybe interesting is, that when I add the flag `-density 10`, the pdf viewer shows me that the pdf has the format `A1` (with very crappy quality). I played with the resolution (density) in the past, but I didn't found out to which value I have to set it so that it works.

Comment: See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#page. A4 has physical dimensions of 8-1/4 x 11-3/4 (see https://www.neenahpaper.com/resources/paper-101/international-sizes). If you divide 842/11.75=72. So the density should be 72 dpi.  My question is did you want all three files on one PDF page or as in my command each file on a different PDF page?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes I want `file1.png` on page 1, `file2.png` on page 2 etc (which is happening right now. Just the papersize is wrong). It also doesn't help, if I add `-density 72` to my command (72 should be default too on ImageMagick as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work properly for me on ImageMagick.

```
convert -size 4961x7016 xc:red xc:green1 xc:blue -resize 595x842 result.pdf
```

```
identify result.pdf
result.pdf[0] PDF 595x841 595x841+0+0 16-bit sRGB 6215B 0.000u 0:00.002
result.pdf[1] PDF 595x841 595x841+0+0 16-bit sRGB 6215B 0.000u 0:00.001
result.pdf[2] PDF 595x841 595x841+0+0 16-bit sRGB 6215B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

```
identify -verbose result.pdf
Image:
  Filename: result.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 595x841+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 8.26389x11.6806  <--- this is close to the expected size for A4 of 8 1/4 x 11 3/4 inches.
```

Are you confused about inches and centimeters?

Comment: Checked the `identify` output now as well (se in the original post as EDIT since this is better readable than here in the comments), and from the identify output it makes totally sense that the pdf is displayed too small, but from my perspective it doesn't make sense that the identify output looks this way.

Comment: Added two sample files too which do not work for me (these are other files than the ones I want to convert, since those are confidential).